# View/Edit mode used in data tables

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, drop-down-list, dashboard

I am working on data table for HR managers that implements in-line editing as well as drop-down menu with detailed options. In-line edit is a must as it will be re-used in dashboard for different pop-ups so we chose in-line edit instead of pop-ups so it wouldn't turn out as a pop-up on a pop-up. The thing is that I was just told to show different values during edit and view mode, in a new iteration of wireframes, as some of the items are not editable. I was told to think of somewhat more elegant solution than I have right now. Please bear with me I started to get into UX just couple of months ago and I am an intern in the company.

Anyways my question: Is there a correct approach to designing detailed dropdown options and follow-up question can you think of more elegant solution to my problem? Any ideas and examples are appreciated.

Here are wireframes of what I have so far. The non-editable fields are : Created on, Lastly modified on, Modified by.

Edit mode

[image: Edit mode]

View mode

[image: View mode]

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is elegant and user-friendly (btw it's called 'Expandable Row').

I can suggest the 'Quick View' option as an alternative that might be preferable since it doesn't alter the table's view: when clicking on 'edit row', a sidebar slides from the side with the details ready to be updated:
[image: Quick view]

This is the resource I use when designing tables: [Design better data tables](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356) (Highly recommended).

Comment: Thanks. Figured the proper name just a few minutes ago by googling :D. I just need to figure out how to divide the details in better matter and hope I'll pitch it to them. 

Saw the resources already, that's why I came up with the in-line edit.  The "Quick View" option is unfortunately not viable but it was my second choice as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shield UI Grid editing section](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/cell-editing-autosync) show a lot of different editing scenarios and types, that you can take a look at and choose the best one for your case.